# Python Script doesn't work properly as Geoprocessing Service

Tags: python, apache-flex, gis, arcgis-server

I have banged my head against the wall on this for days now, I need help. 
I’m trying to create a geoprocessing service (which will be used via a flex viewer) that takes permit information from a GDB, writes it to a file, and then opens it on the user’s computer.

The script I have written works perfectly on local computers and when run from the server itself. 
However, as soon as the script has been published as a geoprocessing service, it stops opening the file.

The file is created out on a webserver, and then opened via url so that the user can then make a local copy, print out for signature, etc. The file is still being created, named, and placed in the proper folder, it just isn’t being opened at end of the process. (The GP Service views as completed though, it doesn’t fail)

Here is the end of the code, which is the part relevant to my issue:

```
f = open(r'\\MyWebAddressHere\\Reports\\Permit' + str(PermitNumber) +'.html','w')

f.write(permitStart)        
if (BasePermitFee > 0):  
    f.write(permitBaseFee)        
if (PlumbingFee > 0):
    f.write(permitPlumbingFee)        
if (ElectricFee > 0):
    f.write(permitElectricFee)              
if (TotalFees > 0):
    f.write(permitTotalFee)
f.write(permitEnd)

f.close()               

webbrowser.open('MyWebAddressHere/Reports/Permit' + str(PermitNumber) +'.html')
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on why the open is failing once the GP service is published?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this as a bug - the `webbrowser` command makes no sense in the context of a GP Service. Think about what's being executed where.

If you run the code locally, Python is running on your actual computer - that computer has a login, a display, a set of installed programs. Telling it to open a web browser makes sense because you have one or more browsers installed on that computer.

Run it on the server, while logged into the server, and same thing - you still have a login, a set of installed programs. While you might lock down a server to reduce its vulnerability, it probably still has at least one program installed that is capable of browsing the internet.

But when you run a script as a GP Tool, you're in a different world. You're not running the code locally, and *you're not logged into the server*. If you execute the `webbrowser` command, where should it open the browser window?

- On your PC? It can't - the server's GP environment can't execute random programs on your PC, that would be a massive security hole. Hey, I'll write a script that deletes everything in C:\Windows and publish it on ArcGIS Online!
- On the server? Who would see it? No one's logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the webbrowser command flat out does not work in a server environment.

I managed to confuse the heck out of an ESRI server analyst with this one, because there is apparently no documentation saying this won't work in a server environment, it just doesn't. So it has been logged as a bug.